# Confusing BIOS and UEFI

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, boot, bios, uefi

I've just bought an Acer Aspire E1 (572) laptop four days ago, and ran into that UEFI/BIOS problem.

1. It was shipped with Linpus Lite OS by default.
2. I had it installed a Win 8 pro on it, after disappointing attempts to do it by myself. It's installed in BIOS mode.

My questions:

1. What's difference between installing an OS on BIOS or UEFI mode?? For example Win 8 must be installed in BIOS mode or what??
2. I want to be able to format my Windows as I did before. I mean I want to remove Win 8 pro and install Win 7, reallocate partitions once in while install Linux distros and so on, because I'm a software engineer and yet can do little with this new mess!! Now I want to remove Win 8 and install Win 7 instead and Ubuntu alongside but I have NO clue how to do so!!
3. I don't want to be thinking I've just wasted my money for some stupid reasons by big selfish companies. Please help me out!!

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 4):

> What's difference between installing an OS on BIOS or UEFI mode?? For
>   example Win 8 must be installed in BIOS mode or what??

Simplest difference is the fact you will be unable to use GPT partitions which means your unable to use 2TB+ drives.  There are ways to do it, involves doing a few things, but the main system partition is limited to 2TB.  **This limitation only exists with Windows.**

> I want to be able to format my Windows as I did before. I mean I want
>   to remove Win 8 pro and install Win 7, reallocate partitions once in
>   while install Linux distros and so on, because I'm a software engineer
>   and yet can do little with this new mess!! Now I want to remove Win 8
>   and install Win 7 instead and Ubuntu alongside but I have NO clue how
>   to do so!!

This process is well documented.  The simplest steps would be to format the HDD, install Windows 7, then install Ubuntu.